# Remover nodos creados usando EventListener

Tags: javascript, eventos, dom

Hace unas semanas empecé con `JavaScript`, acabo de aprender a utilizar `EventListener`, por favor ayúdenme, ¿cómo puedo remover un nodo creado usando `EventListener`?.

En el ejemplo que mostraré más abajo asigno un EventListener a un botón para que genere nodos (cajas div), lo que quiero es poder dar clic sobre cada caja creada para removerla.

Hice el siguiente código pero no está funcionando para remover los nodos creados, solamente funciona si tengo las cajas div agregadas manualmente en el HTML y llamándolos con su id. Aquí el código:

```
// FUNCION PARA CREAR CAJA
function createBox() {
  var box = document.createElement('div');
  box.className = 'box';
  box.id = 'newBox';
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  container.appendChild(box);
}

// EVENTO PARA CLIC BOTÓN Y CREAR CAJA
var createUnit = document.getElementById('btn');
createUnit.addEventListener('click', createBox);

// FUNCION PARA REMOVER CAJA
function deleteBox() {
 var deleteBox = document.getElementById('newBox').remove();
 this.remove();
}

/* EVENTO PARA CLIC CAJA Y REMOVER
aquí invoco por el id newBox que asigné más arriba */

var deleteUnit = document.getElementById('newBox');
deleteUnit.addEventListener('click', deleteBox);
```

En la consola me figura el error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es porque intentas acceder a un elemento que  no ha sido agregado al `document`. entonces la línea

```
var deleteUnit = document.getElementById('newBox');
```

Retornará `null` , por lo tanto no podrá añadir el `evento`. Si desea que existe el elemento con id `newBox` tendrá que llamar al método `createBox()` para que pueda existir en el `document`.

```
createBox();
var deleteUnit = document.getElementById('newBox');
deleteUnit.addEventListener('click', deleteBox);
```

Ahora si desea añadir el mismo `evento` a los elementos creados con el botón, deberá agregar el `addEventListener` dentro del método `createBox()` ya que en principio `JavaScript`  ya se ejecutó y solo se añadió el `listener` al elemento que creo *(a los elementos con el id o clase que existan en el dom)* al llamar a la función manualmente.

Otra observación es que dentro del método eliminar no es necesario buscar nuevamente el elemento con `getElementById` , el elemento al que se dio `click` se puede referenciar con `this` directamente.

**`Además como recomendación el ID debe ser Único en el DOM`** , por lo tanto en mi ejemplo hago uso de `getElementsByClassName` que retorna una colección y con `[0]` accedo al primer elemento que sería el que se creo. Estás líneas las dejo en el código por si acaso desee que por defecto se muestre una caja al cargar el `document`.

Código final

```js
function createBox() {
  var box = document.createElement('div');
  box.className = 'box';
  box.addEventListener('click',deleteBox);
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  container.appendChild(box);
}

// EVENTO PARA CLIC BOTÓN Y CREAR CAJA
var createUnit = document.getElementById('btn');
createUnit.addEventListener('click', createBox);

// FUNCION PARA REMOVER CAJA
function deleteBox() {
 this.remove();
}

/* EVENTO PARA CLIC CAJA Y REMOVER
aquí invoco por el id newBox que asigné más arriba */
createBox();
var deleteUnit = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0];
deleteUnit.addEventListener('click', deleteBox);
```

```css
.box{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin:1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">  
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Agregar"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que tendrias que hacer es lo siguiente, al nuevo elemento que creaste añadir el metodo onClick en la etiqueta html para que ejecute la funcion delete box, harias lo siguiente:

```
// FUNCION PARA CREAR CAJA
function createBox() {
  var box = document.createElement('div');
  box.className = 'box';
  box.id = 'newBox';
// Evento para eliminar la caja
  box.onclick = deleteBox();
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  container.appendChild(box);
}

// EVENTO PARA CLIC BOTÓN Y CREAR CAJA
var createUnit = document.getElementById('btn');
createUnit.addEventListener('click', createBox());

// FUNCION PARA REMOVER CAJA
function deleteBox() {
 this.remove();
}
```

Alguien que pruebe ese y me diga en que falla, pues no lo puedo probar porque lo hice desde el celular